# Creating folder structure using high_voltage gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm trying to use the [high_voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) gem to serve static pages in my Rails app. What I want is for individual sections to get their own folder, but can't quite get it to work & can't find a solution around the web.

**What I want:**

RAILS_ROOT/app/views/pages/(page) to be routed as '/(page)' 
While RAILS_ROOT/app/views/pages/(directory)/(page) => '/(directory)/(page)'

**Here's my attempt:**

routes.rb:

```
Cam4::Application.routes.draw do

  root :to => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :id => 'index'
  match '/:id' => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :as => :static, :via => :get

  scope "ruby" do
    match '/ruby/:id' => 'high_voltage/pages/ruby#show', :as => :static, :via => :get
  end

end
```

Thanks a lot,

Cameron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually ended up solving the problem on my own using route globbing.
Given a Rails 3.2.5 app running high_voltage, with view paths:

> RAILS_ROOT/app/views/pages/id **[=> '/pages/id' or just '/id']** 
>   RAILS_ROOT/app/views/pages/ruby/id **[=> 'pages/ruby/id' or 'ruby/id']**

Routes.rb:

```
Cam4::Application.routes.draw do

  root :to => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :id => 'index'
  match '/*id' => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :as => :static, :via => :get

end
```